# how to install warzone 2100 ver3.1game from tar.gz file

Tags: games

I tried ./configure but resulted in error :

"checking for GLEW... configure: error: Package requirements (glew >= 1.5.2) were not met:

No package 'glew' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GLEW_CFLAGS
and GLEW_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details."

Pls help

I have got libglew already installed

Comment: You installed `libglew-dev`?

Comment: thanks,it worked when it demanded glew i just searched for glew alone in synaptic.it didn't returned dev package now i installed it explicitly for cmdline

Comment: Excellent. Remember to always install the development purpose version of a package `package_name-dev` when you require it to build a package from its source code.

Answer (score 1):

When you are run `./configure` and if trows some error message like

```
checking for GLEW... configure: error: Package requirements (glew >= 1.5.2) were not met:
No package 'glew' found.
problem pakage name => GLEW
```

run:

```
apt-cache dump | grep -E 'Package.*glew'
```

It will show some packages like `Package: libglew-dev`

=> template is "lib[problem-pakage-name]-dev"

run:

```
sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
```

run again:  `./configure`

if you find some another problem pakage then start this procedure first line...

Answer (score 0):

To respect the format of Q-A demanded by the site, here I write the solution to this problem.

When a package you are going to build has dependencies which you have to install from a software repository, always attempt to install the development version of the package, i.e. `package_name-dev`, since only this one will install the source code required to build the first package.